# How to back and forth in array of data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I have a following data which I am iterating on paragraph, which performs different task in different steps. I am not getting how to load selected view and controller in angular and make current as active.

http://prntscr.com/fisflz

```
[{
        "0" : {
            "name" : "Select Event"
        }, 
        "1" : {
            "name" : "Connect" 
        }, 
        "2" : {
            "name" : "Configure" 
        }, 
        "3" : {
            "name" : "Test" 
        }, 
        "4" : {
            "name" : "Finish"
        }
    }]
```

Hint will appreciable. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi @udaykumar, I hope you can set a $rootScope value in $statechange and use it to highlight the text..!!1

Comment: If your question is about the basic angular routing, please follow the getting started tutorial or if it's something else, please create a plunkr about what you are trying to do ?